# How to add secondary links to dabeng org chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, orgchart

I want to add dotted line to this chart eg. leaf level nodes to have indirect link to middle level node, 
Script.js

```
import OrgChart from '../js/orgchart.min.js';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  Mock.mock('/orgchart/initdata', {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
            { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Yu Li', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Yu Wei', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'name': 'Yu Tie', 'title': 'department manager' }
      ]
    });
  Mock.setup({ timeout: 1000 });

  let orgchart = new OrgChart({
    'chartContainer': '#chart-container',
    'data' : '/orgchart/initdata',
    'depth': 2,
    'nodeContent': 'title'
  });

});
```

This is the code provided by dabeng org chart plugin.

I want to add secondary/Indirect links in this chart but, i am unable to add! Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you put forward a challenging issue for plugin OrgChart. In fact, if you have reviewed the source code of OrgChart, you will find that the core logic of OrgChart plugin is to draw tree-like structure with nested table tags. The lines between the different nodes are just borders of td tags. It's impossible to draw random links between different nodes in different levels right now.